# jQuery: mouseover triggered only from the second hover

Tags: jquery, html, hover, tooltip, mouseover

for some reason i need to put my mouse over "Details" anchor twice for the tooltip to appear. Why is that?

HTML code bit:

```
<a class="tt" data-animation="grow" data-position="left" data-speed="500" data-offsetx="41" data-offsety="38" data-maxwidth="683" data-interactive="true" data-theme=".tooltipster-standard" title="<div><h1>Package Name<span>£99.99</span></h1></div>">Details</a>
```

jQuery code:

```
    $('.tt').mouseover(function(e){
        $(this).tooltipster(addCaps($(this).data()));
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `tooltipster()` sets up the tooltip, it doesn't show it.

So your first mouseover sets up the tooltip, then the second shows the tooltip.

Try this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tt').each(function(e){
        $(this).tooltipster(addCaps($(this).data()));
    });  
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You Could Use Something Like That To HTML:

```
<a class="tt" OnMouseOver="Hover()" ...other attributes and tags
```

From Javascript(JQUERY) side:

```
function Hover(){
$(this).tooltipster(addCaps($(this).data()));
}
```

Or Created with pure JavaScript:

```
document.querySelector(".tt").addEventListener("onmouseover",function(){

$(this).tooltipster(addCaps($(this).data()));

},false);
```

Or Created it with Jquery :

```
$(".tt").hover(function(){
$(this).tooltipster(addCaps($(this).data()));
}
```

Explination:
This is due That mouseover jQuery methode Work When The User's Mouse is already in and move over That You need to enter the area first than move the mouse over it again also hover include enter and over that's why it work.
+ As My Friend Said Upgrade your Version of JQUERY. 
That My Point If View Any Comments or suggestion are welcomed :)

Answer (score 0):

Try [**mouseenter**](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) to ensure tooltipster is called once when entering.

```
$('.tt').mouseenter(function(e){
    $(this).tooltipster(addCaps($(this).data()));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use the `hover` instead of `mouseover` also consider to upgrade the jQuery version.